# Android thread, switch activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I have this problem working with Threads on Android.
How can I kill a thread and start another activity? It works but when it switches, gives an force close error.
here is the activity running:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

OurView v;
FileManager fis;
Clock clk;
public float xPos,yPos;
TargetFactory targ = new TargetFactory();
Target target = targ.makeTarget(1);
static int score = 0;
int width = 100;
int height = 200;
static User us  = User.getInstance();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    v = new OurView(this);
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    fis= new FileManager(this);
    setContentView(v);
    clk = new Clock();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    startActivity(new Intent(Game.this,Result.class));
    v.pause();
}

@Override
public synchronized boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

    xPos = me.getX();
    yPos = me.getY();
    target = targ.makeTarget((int) (Math.random()*20));
    switch(me.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(target.targetMove(xPos, yPos, width, height)){
            score ++;
            us.setScore(score);
        }
        else
        {
            score --;
            us.setScore(score);
        }
        break;
    }

    return false;
}


public static int getScore(){
    return score;
}

public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        User us = User.getInstance();

        boolean ok = false;
        public OurView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(ok == true){
                if(Clock.getSeconds() < 5){             
                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                Paint p = paint(c);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }else{
                    pause();
                    continue;

                }
            }       
        }

        public Paint paint(Canvas c) {
            width = c.getWidth();
            height = c.getHeight();
            c.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            target.drawTarget(c);
            c.drawText(""+score, c.getWidth()-20,20, p);
            return p;
        }

        public void pause(){
            ok = false;
            fis.writeToFile(us);
            t.interrupt();

        } 
        public void checkForPaused() {
            while (ok == false) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
    }

        public void resume(){
            target.reset(width, height);
            ok = true;
            t.start();

        }
    }}
```

And this is the one im trying to start:

```
public class Result extends Activity {

TextView result;
Button restart;
Button toMenu;
User us = User.getInstance();
FileManager fis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    fis = new FileManager(this);

    fis.readFromFile();
    setContentView(R.layout.result);


    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    String s = us.getName()+" Result: "+us.getScore();
    result.setText(s);



    restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart);
    restart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Result.this,Game.class));

        }
    });


    toMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retmenu);
    toMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Result.this,Menu.class));

        }
    });
}}
```

Sorry for my bad enghlish, and sorry if i wrote to much code but i dont know where the problem is.

```
LogCat:
06-01 10:51:00.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3302): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10

06-01 10:51:00.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3302): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

06-01 10:51:00.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3302):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)

06-01 10:51:00.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3302):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:358)

06-01 10:51:00.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3302):     at com.example.firstone.Game$OurView.pause(Game.java:140)

06-01 10:51:00.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3302):     at com.example.firstone.Game$OurView.run(Game.java:118)

06-01 10:51:00.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3302):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

So I managed to fix the problem by calling the finish() method. This stops the activity so it stops the thread.

Comment: Can you please post the LogCat output? This will allow us to figure out what is  making it crash. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkForPaused() {
            while (ok == false) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
```

How you can sleep thread, if he interrupt in pause?:

```
  public void pause(){
            ok = false;
            fis.writeToFile(us);
            t.interrupt();

        }
```

Its one. Two:You stop thread, when set flag to false. Interrupt dont need.

Answer (score 0):

```
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //empty catch blocks are a terrible habit! Please at least use Log.w!
            }
```

Apart from that, you're misusing the Thread state changing methods of Object. When you call interrupt on an object, it interrupts the thread in that specific object instance's Monitor. A thread enters the Monitor of an object when you are using a 'synchronized' block linked to a specific object, for example synchronized(this). In this case, you assumed that the Thread itself becomes interrupted, rather than calling interrupt on something that keeps track of the Thread that is inside it. Hence why you receive an IllegalMonitorStateException when you use interrupt: the Thread is not in the Monitor of any Object, therefore it is an illegal state.

Interrupting threads is usually a bad way of handling things to begin with. If you want to end a thread, use a flag that tells the thread to leave its loop.